# Query is not running when i try to run it using mysql_query() command

Tags: php

I am trying to test if this query runs or not.But i am output with blank screen i.e no output. I am using xampp server.

```
<?php
$mysql_host='localhost'; 
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_pass='';
$mysql_db='a_database';
$con_error='connection error';
$query="SELECT `name`  FROM `users` WHERE `id`='1' "; //selecting name from databas where id is 1
$query_run=mysql_query($query); //this is my query 

if($query_run)
  {

   echo 'success';
  }

?>
```

Please help me with this. `$query_run` neither returns false here nor true. I am not able to understand where the problem is.

Comment: have you established the connection to your database.?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to avoid `mysql_*` functions from `php > 5.4`, use `mysqli_*` function like this.
connect to Databse before running a query like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); 
$query="SELECT `name`  FROM `users` WHERE `id`='1' "; //selecting name from databas where id is 1
$query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

For `php < 5.5` use this

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); 
$query="SELECT `name`  FROM `users` WHERE `id`='1' "; //selecting name from databas where id is 1
$query_run=mysql_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all stop using `mysql` it is deprecated. Use `mysqli` now.

In your script you missed the connection to database. Add before your query:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

For more details see [this](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect) link.

Answer (score 0):

try this:::

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","a_database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "SELECT name FROM users" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
$result = $link->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
} 
?>
```

as mentioned there, use `mysqli_*`